# After running python manage.py createsuperuser nothing happened

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-manage.py

I am trying to createsuperuser. I'm in my project. When I type  `python manage.py createsuperuser` nothing happens, it looks like POWERSHELL has hung up. After this command I only see blank page without next line to enter next command.

I'm learning from tutorial:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=1752s

Step on which I got suck: 17 minutes 45 seconds

```
(trydjango) PS C:\Users\piotr\dev\trydjango\src> python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: did you run `python manage.py migrate` first?

Comment: I ran python manage.py and it says everything is ok

Comment: You still need to run `python manage.py migrate` first so that database tables are created which will store your user

Comment: ```Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.```

Comment: I've just typed it and nothing happened

Comment: 'python manage.py runserver' is working?

Comment: When I typed ```python manage.py runserver``` nothing occurs

Comment: and you did 'makemigrations' ?

Comment: First I typed ```python manage.py makemigrations```, then I typed        
  ```python manage.py migrate```, then ``` python manage.py runserver``` and after that nothing occurs: only this: ```python : Watching for file changes with StatReloader
At line:1 char:1
+ python manage.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Watching for fi...th StatReloader:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because user might have terminated server in the background

run *python manage.py runserver* in one powershell window

and in another window execute *python manage.py migrate* & *python manage.py createsuperuser*

Then ISE will ask for username, email etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).